# Python requests - org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

first time posting on here so apologies in advance if I get any of the etiquette wrong.

I'm writing some code in python 3 using requests, to log in to a website and it should return me another page after logging in.

I've used Google Chromes developer tools to see what Form Data needs to be included in the payload, and what I believe is causing the problem is the org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN, which is unique on each form submission.

Does anyone know how to get around this? Or is it another issue? 
Currently its returning me a page telling me "Details Incorrect". I have logged onto the site manually with these details though, to record the data sent during the login.

My code is below.

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:

payload = {"org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN": this is unique on each form submission,
           "loginRegNo": xxxxxxx, "loginPin": xxxxxx}
headers = {"Accept": "text/html",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Content-Length": "105",
           "2Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=xxxxxx,
           "Host": "www.website.ie",
           "Origin": "https://www.website.ie",
           "Pragma": "no-cache",
           "Referer": "https://www.website.ie/OMT/omt.do",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                         "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36}"
           }

p = s.post("https://www.website.ie/OMT/omt.do", data=payload, headers=headers, cookies=s.cookies)
# print the status code to see if it's successful
print(p.status_code)

r = s.get("https://www.website.ie/OMT/login.do", cookies=s.cookies)
print(r.text)
print(r.url)

print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: What do you put into "org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should

```
 - p = s.get("https://www.website.ie/OMT/omt.do")
 - extract the token generated for that session from the org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN input element of p
 - add the extracted token to the payload, beside loginRegNo and loginPin
 - (you might not need to add Cookie and Content-Length headers)
 - s.post("https://www.website.ie/OMT/login.do", data=payload, headers=headers, cookies=s.cookies)
```

Note that I GET `https://www.website.ie/OMT/omt.do` and POST against `https://www.website.ie/OMT/login.do` .

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the token via beautifulsoup.

use urllib2 to get the page, parse it via beautifulsoup and find the token within the html doc

it will probably look like this:

```py
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = urllib2.urlopen('..') # your url

soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

You will se the output and hopefully where the token is stored. After you found the position of the token within the html document, you will be able to access it via
`soup.body.input` or something like that.

hope that helps :)